# Exit code 139 when using const char*

Tags: c++

so I am writing a program that counts the number of occurrences of the character **x** in a **const char*** called **p**. but I get **Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)** when running the program.
At first I ran this code in Visual Studio and it didn't work so I thought it might be a Windows issue but the error code above is what I got when running the same program in Clion in Ubuntu 20.04!!
I would appreciate it if anyone could answer my question.
The code is written below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int count_x(const char* s, const char x)
{
    if(!s){return 0;}

    int count = 0;
    while(s)
    {
        if(*s == x)
            ++count;
        ++s;
    }

    return count;
}

int main()
{
    const char* s = "Hello";
    const char x = 'l';
    int count = count_x(s, x);

    cout << count;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while(s)` should be `while(*s)` (to detect the nul character at the end of the string).  As it is, you are running off the end of the string.  Also, `if(!s){return 0;}` is unnecessary (and also faulty).

Comment: voice of experience - if you think its a bug in the toolchain or the OS you are almost always wrong

Comment: It's worth restating what pm100 said here. If you think it's a bug in Windows or a bug in the compiler then 99,999 times out of 100,000 you will be wrong. These kinds of bugs are extremely rare, so focus instead on common ones: Off-by-one errors, referencing an array out of bounds, using uninitialized values, and use-after-free. Keep that list taped to your screen if you must as at least 80% of your bugs will be one of those.

Comment: @pm100 Too many times that has shown the problem to be my own dumb fault.

Comment: And turn on as many warnings as you can. That will find a vast number of bugs.

Comment: @cigien - always feel that the defaults should be -Wall -Werror

Comment: @pm100 Agreed. Better to err on the side of too many though :)

Comment: @PaulSanders if i understood correctly the pointer at the end of a char* string isn't necessarily a nullpointer ?(Thanks for the answer)

Comment: It's a zero byte, no pointers involved.

Comment: Don't confuse NUL (character) with NULL (pointer) with C++ `nullptr` (NULL pointer).

Comment: I wrote this piece of code based of a "tour of c++" written by good old bjarne stroustrup and here i was thinking that i had pointers all figured out :( thanks to all of you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the string "Hello" actually is stored like this

```
H e l l o \0
```

that last char is called the zero terminator

So the while loop needs to look at the char s is pointing at
and to stop if the character is logically false - ie equal to 0.

```
while(*s)
{
    if(*s == x)
        ++count;
    ++s;
}
```

or more explicitly but less idiomatic

```
while(*s != '\0')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the pointer value in your code, not the pointed to value.

```cpp
while(s /* Here */) {
    if(*s == x)
        ++count;
    ++s;
}
```

You can fix this by adding `*` before the pointer name

```cpp
while(*s) {
    if(*s == x)
        ++count;
    ++s;
}
```